# Creating a function to replace certain letters in a string?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I need to create   a   function    that    accepts two chars   and a   string  and returns a   string.
The function    should  replace all letters in  the first   parameter   with    the second
parameter.
For example,    if  the string  passed  is  “How    now cow”    and the function    replaces
all ‘o’ to  ‘e’ then    the new string  would   be: “Hew    new cew”.

I know this is wrong, but how could I modify this code to work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string replace(char a, char b, string Rstring){
string Restring;

Restring= Rstring.replace( 'o', 2, 'e')

return Restring;
}

int countspace(string  mystring){
int counter;
for (int i=0;i<mystring.length();i++){

if (mystring[i]== ' ')
counter++;
}
return counter;


}
```

Comment: The replace function, but it's a little difficult for me to figure out since the string that's being accepted is user generated.

Comment: Post the code that you've written that isn't working. As it is, you're basically asking for someone to do it for you.

Comment: Hint:  `std::string::find`.  Use a pen and paper and write down the steps you would take to solve the requirements.  Now, convert those steps into programming instructions.

Comment: Helpful tip, thanks, I was using the wrong function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string.replace` will not do what you want. Instead you should write your own method, it's not too tough to do this parsing.

```
 replaceChars(string *str, char old, char replacement)
 {
      for(char& c : str) {
         if (c == old)
            c = replacement;
      }
 }
```

That loop will only work in C++11 so if it doesn't work use this insead;

```
     while(char* it = str; *it; ++it) {
          if (*it == old) // dereference the pointer, we want the char not the address
            *it = replacement;
      }
```

You pass this a pointer to the string and the chars you want to swap. It loops over the string char by char, when you you encounter the old char you set that to replacement. The for loop uses a reference to `c` so you will be changing the string in place, no need to allocate a new string or anything. If you're not using `std::string` this can be done just as easily with a character array. The concept is exactly the same.